# Pagination records per page in select option

Tags: php, pagination

I am creating a dynamic table and I want to have custom select option for the Records per Page. I look on a site but it doesn't have select option for pages

My idea is like this:

I want to change the **`$per_page`** to a PHP tag but it gives me an error if i use `$_GET` and `$_POST`.. thanks for the help

```
<form method="GET">
 <select id="records" name="records"> 
            <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
            <option  value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">Mostra tutti</option>
            </select><li>
            <li><input type = "submit" class = button2 name = "btnsubmit"></li>
            </form>
 </ul></nav> 

<?php
$page_name="admin_list.php";
$per_page = 10 ;

      if ($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM clienti  WHERE utenza =1  OR utenza =0 ORDER BY es_insegna_esercizio"))
      {

      if ($result->num_rows != 0)
      {
      $total_results = $result->num_rows;
      // ceil() returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary

      $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

      // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
      if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
      {
      $show_page = $_GET['page'];

      // make sure the $show_page value is valid
      if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
      {
      $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
      $end = $start + $per_page;
      }
      else
      {
      // error - show first set of results
      $start = 0;
      $end = $per_page;
      }
      }
      else
      {
      // if page isn't set, show first set of results
      $start = 0;
      $end = $per_page;
      }

      echo "<table id='my_table' class='tables' name ='tablename'>";

          echo "

          <thead><tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>
                <input type = checkbox >
                    </th>
                    <th>Azienda</th>
                     <th>Utente</th>
                     <th>Cognome</th>

          </tr></thead>
              " ;

          // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
          for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++){
          // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
          if ($i == $total_results) { break; }
          // find specific row
          $result->data_seek($i);
          $row = $result->fetch_row();
          // echo out the contents of each row into a table
          echo "<tr>";

              echo '<td><img src ="images/edit_icon.png"class = "autoResizeImage" onclick="JavaScript:newPopup(\'admin_edit.php?id='.$row['0'].'\')" /></td>';
              echo '<td><input type=checkbox name=chk[] class= chk-box value='.$row[0].'/></td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row[14] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row[2]. '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row[3] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row[4] . '</td>';

              echo "</tr>";
          }
          // close table>
          echo "</table></form>";  
      }
      else{
      echo "No results to display!";
      }
      }
      // error with the query
      else{
      echo "Error: " . $con->error;
      }
    echo "<p> 
 <b>View Page: </b>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++){
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $i){
    echo  $i;
    }
    else{
    echo "<a href='admin_list.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
    }
    }  

    echo "</p>";
    // close database connection
      $con->close();

?>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a form and a PHP code that will get the submitted value. Try this code out

```
<form method="GET">
      <select name="records"> 
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" selected>3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
      $per_page = 30 ;

      if(isset($_GET['submit']) && !empty($_GET['records']) && preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_GET['records'])) {
      /* Is the form submitted + is the records set + is the records an integer*/
            $per_page = $_GET['records'];
      }

      if($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM clienti  WHERE utenza = 1 OR utenza = 0 ORDER BY es_insegna_esercizio")) {
            if($result->num_rows != 0) {
                  $total_results = $result->num_rows; // How many records do we have?
                  $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page); // How many pages do we have?

                  if(!empty($_GET['page']) && preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] <= $total_pages) {
                  /* is the page set + is it an integer + is it <= of total pages*/
                        $show_page = $_GET['page'];
                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                        $end = $start + $per_page;
                  }  else {
                        $start = 0;
                        $end = $per_page;
                  }
            }
      }
```

Comment: the option is working but if i click the page numbers , the results go back to 30 per row thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying. Can you explain your problem a bit better?

Comment: the Option works and the no, of rows changes now but when i click the next page for example 1 [2] 3 4 5. the number of rows return to the deafult  per page value of 30 instead of the selected value . thanks

Comment: Ok i've updated my code. Now just add $_GET['records'] parameter to the page number links. If you don't understand me, just update your question with the code for 1 [2] 3 4 5

Comment: ive updated the old code with view page. thanks a lot

Comment: Change `echo "<a href='admin_list.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";` to `echo "<a href='admin_list.php?page=".$i."&records=".$per_page."'>".$i."</a> ";`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select id="records" name="records"> 
        <option  value="10">10</option>
        <option  value="20">20</option>
        <option  selected value="30">30</option>
        <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "submit" name = "record">

 $per_page = 30 ;

 if(isset($_GET["records"]) && $_GET["records"] > 0)
 {
     $per_page = $_GET["records"] ;     
 }


  if ($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM clienti  WHERE utenza =1 OR utenza =0 ORDER BY es_insegna_esercizio"))
  {

  if ($result->num_rows != 0)
  {
  $total_results = $result->num_rows;
  // ceil() returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary

  $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

  // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated.php?page=1)
  if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
  {
  $show_page = $_GET['page'];

  // make sure the $show_page value is valid
  if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
  {
  $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
  $end = $start + $per_page;
  }
  else
  {
  // error - show first set of results
  $start = 0;
  $end = $per_page;
  }
  }
  else
  {
  // if page isn't set, show first set of results
  $start = 0;
  $end = $per_page;
```

You just need to add 'name' attribute in  element. and add condition for 'records'. Kindly use this one. Your issue will be solved.

Also, If you use 'POST' method, then use $_POST method in condition.

Comment: the number of pages doesnt change

Comment: can you pls give me your script? i mean your code with <form> tag

Comment: <form method="GET">
 <select id="records" name="records"> 
    <option value="10">10</option>
     <option value="2">20</option>
    <option  value="3">30</option>
    <option  value="40">40</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "submit" name = "records">
    </form>

Comment: <form method="GET"> <select id="records" name="records"> <option value="10">10</option> <option value="20">20</option> <option value="30">30</option> <option value="40">40</option> </select> <input type = "submit" name = "btnSubmit"> </form>


You need to change your submit button 'name' attribute. use this one..

Also, I have modified code. Please check this